# Can't retrieve image from SQL Server using Generic Handler c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, httphandler, ashx

Whenever I retrieve an image using my Generic Handler, I retrieve either an empty image or a broken image.

Here is my code.

aspx File:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

//imports
using DHELTASSys.Modules;
using System.Data;
using DHELTASSys.AuditTrail;

namespace DHELTASSys
{
    public partial class EvaluateOffense : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        DisciplineModuleBL discipline = new DisciplineModuleBL();
        DHELTASSysAuditTrail audit = new DHELTASSysAuditTrail();

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string position = Session["Position"].ToString();
            if (Session["EmployeeID"] == null)
            {
                Response.Redirect("LogIn.aspx");
            } else if(position != "HR Manager")
            {
                Response.Redirect("AccessDenied.aspx");
            }

            discipline.Offense_emp_id = int.Parse(Session["OffenseID"].ToString());

            DataTable dt = discipline.GetProof();

            if (dt.Rows == null)
            {

                Label9.Visible = false;
                Image1.Visible = false;
            }
        }



        protected void btnEvaluate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            discipline.Offense_emp_id = int.Parse(Session["OffenseID"].ToString());
            discipline.Decision = drpDecision.Text;

            discipline.AddOffenseDecision();

            audit.Emp_id = int.Parse(Session["EmployeeID"].ToString());
            audit.AddAuditTrail(drpDecision.Text + "ed Employee's offense.");

        }
    }
}
```

Here is the handler:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.IO;

//imports
using System.Data;
using DHELTASSys.Modules;
using DHELTASSys.DataAccess;

namespace DHELTASSys
{

    public class ShowImage : IHttpHandler, System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState
    {
        DisciplineModuleBL discipline = new DisciplineModuleBL();
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            if (context.Session["OffenseID"].ToString() == null) return;
            int offense_emp_id = int.Parse(context.Session["OffenseID"].ToString());
            discipline.Offense_emp_id = offense_emp_id;

            DataTable dt = discipline.GetProof();

            if (dt.Rows == null) return;

            int id = 1;

            string image = dt.Rows[0][1].ToString() + id;

            string FileName = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
            string FileContentType = dt.Rows[0][2].ToString();

            Byte[] bytes = (Byte[])dt.Rows[0][1];

            string imageBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);

            context.Response.ContentType = "image/" + FileContentType;

            if (context.Request.QueryString["id"] == "1")
            {
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

                ms.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                context.Response.Buffer = true;
                System.Drawing.Image imagen = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
                context.Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
                ms.Dispose();

            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }






        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And adding to that, here is my image object.

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/ShowImage.ashx" />
```

I already tweaked my code in so many ways.

The image file is stored in SQL Server using the data type "Image"

As you can see, I'm using the session to retrieve the specified image from the Database.
I have no problem in accessing the session whatsoever.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems a bit more complicated than necessary; you can write the binary data to the outputstream without needing to load it into a memory stream, and you're doing nothing with your `System.Drawing.Image` object. Try this:

`context.Response.OutputStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);`

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint on `bytes` and verifying that you're getting data from the database?

Answer (score 0):

First, I don't see anything wrong with the way you are writing the image to the response stream. There's a few useless lines of code but I understand that as you said, you were tweaking your code in desperation. Basically, this should be good enough...

```
        Byte[] bytes = (Byte[])dt.Rows[0][1];
        context.Response.ContentType = "image/" + FileContentType;

        if (context.Request.QueryString["id"] == "1")
        {
            context.Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
            context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest(); //just to make sure the ASP.NET pipeline completes the request
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
```

Now, that "should" work given that `bytes` has been correctly casted to a byte array. Make sure to add some proper exception handling and logging because I'm a bit suspicious that the problem it's somewhere else. So, follow these steps:

- Clean up your code for better clarity
- Debug the app
- Implement some exception handling
- Implement some sort of error logging

You should be able to get to the bottom of this issue since there's nothing wrong in sending an array of bytes using the `BinaryWrite` method

Answer (score 0):

**This is real example that pickup from my project**

into page.cs set image url dynamically:

```
// for diffrent url using guid in url
imgProfilePic.ImageUrl = "GenericHandler_ShowImage.ashx?Ref=" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "&n=" + lngEmployeeID;
```

into handler, get image by table adapter

```
// in handler
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    long EmployeeID = -1;
    if (context.Request.QueryString["n"] != null)
        EmployeeID = long.Parse(context.Request.QueryString["n"].ToString());
    //else
    //    throw new ArgumentException("No parameter specified");

    if (context.Request.QueryString["actid"] == "2")
    {
        ShowThumbPic(context, EmployeeID);
        return;
    }
        //else ...
}

private void ShowThumbPic(HttpContext context, long EmployeeID)
{
    context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
    Stream myStream = GetEmpImage(EmployeeID);
    byte[] myImgByteArray;

    using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(myStream))
    {
        myImgByteArray = br.ReadBytes((int)myStream.Length);
    }

    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
    System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);

    if (img.Height > 50 || img.Width > 50)
    {
        System.Drawing.Size siz = GetScaledSize(img.Size, new System.Drawing.Size(50, 50));
        img = (System.Drawing.Image)ResizeImage(img, siz);
    }


    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
    byte[] myBuffer = ms.ToArray();
    int byteSeq = myBuffer.Length; //myStream.Read(myBuffer, 0, 4096);
    if (byteSeq > 0)
        context.Response.OutputStream.Write(myBuffer, 0, byteSeq);
}

private System.Drawing.Image GetEmployeeImage(long EmployeeID)
{
    System.Drawing.Image img = null;
    try
    {
        using (DAL.dstEmployeeTableAdapters.tbl_Employee_InfoTableAdapter ta = new DAL.dstEmployeeTableAdapters.tbl_Employee_InfoTableAdapter())
        {
            object obj = ta.spr_Employee_Info_GetPicture(EmployeeID);
            if (obj != null)
            {
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream((byte[])obj);
                img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception x)
    {
        throw new Exception(Msg.Error_InDownloadPicture + x.Message);
    }
    return img;
}

public static Size GetScaledSize(Size ImageSize, Size FrameSize)
{
    int newWidth = ImageSize.Width;
    int newHeight = ImageSize.Height;
    double ratioX = (double)FrameSize.Width / ImageSize.Width;
    double ratioY = (double)FrameSize.Height / ImageSize.Height;
    double ratio = Math.Min(ratioX, ratioY);
    if (ratio < 1.0f) // if Frame is greater than image, resize it.
    {
        newWidth = (int)(ImageSize.Width * ratio);
        newHeight = (int)(ImageSize.Height * ratio);
    }
    return new Size(newWidth, newHeight);
}

public static System.Drawing.Bitmap ResizeImage(System.Drawing.Image image, Size siz)
{
    //a holder for the result
    Bitmap result = new Bitmap(siz.Width, siz.Height);
    // set the resolutions the same to avoid cropping due to resolution differences
    result.SetResolution(image.HorizontalResolution, image.VerticalResolution);

    //use a graphics object to draw the resized image into the bitmap
    using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(result))
    {
        //set the resize quality modes to high quality
        graphics.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
        graphics.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        //draw the image into the target bitmap
        graphics.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, result.Width, result.Height);
    }

    //return the resulting bitmap
    return result;
}
```